# How to get params url parent id from children

Tags: angular, routes

I have this in my route.ts

```
 path: 'profile/:id',
                component: ProfileComponent,
                canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard],
                children: [

                    {
                        path: 'albums',
                        component: AlbumsComponent,
                        canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]

                    },
                               ...
                         ]
```

Now in my profile.ts I got this

```
localhost:4200/profile/45666
```

and when I route to album.ts that is chlidren of my profile.ts

```
localhost:4200/profile/45666/albums
```

Now I'm in my album.ts how can I get the id 45666?

I tried to use ActivatedRoute:

```
console.log(this._route.snapshot.params.id) >> undefined
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `ActivatedRoute` class from `angular/router`

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router"

public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute

this.activatedRoute.parent.params // return observable
```

if you want the static value, then ask for

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.params // return static values
```

By using the attribute parent, you can access to all the parameters and queries from the parent component

Comment: there is an object named _value and the id that I need inside it, I tried to do this `this.activatedRoute.parent.params._value.id` but undefined

Comment: this.activatedRoute.parent.params return a observable, if you want the static values you should ask for this.activatedRoute.parent.snaptshot.params

Answer (score 16):

Since angular `5.2.x` there is another way to access parent params.

All you have to do is set config option [paramsInheritanceStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#paramsInheritanceStrategy) to `'always'` like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
})
```

With this config, you will have access to all ancestor routes params via prototypal inheritance, so you can get it directly from activated route:

`this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params`

Answer (score 2):

You need to import ActivatedRoute from @angular/router:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
```

Then in your constructor of AlbumsComponent you can grab that :id parameter
like this:

```
let id = this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.params["id"]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using activatedRoute you can get id in ngOnInit() method. like

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    var id = params['id'];
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
let idparam = this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.params["idparam"]
```