# Angular - Get Route Parameters from parent route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, route-parameters

I have a global routing module which allows me to correctly navigate to my component module which is lazy loaded.

Inside the component module I have a child route which can be correctly loaded. What I can't seem to do however is access the `userID` parameter from inside the albums path (the child of the userDetailComponent)

I've tried the following, but it returns as undefined.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((urlParameters) => {
  this.user_id = urlParameters['userID'];
}
```

Below is my routing configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
     path: 'users', 
     loadChildren: '../app/users/users.module#UsersModule' 
  },
  {
     path: 'users/:userID',
     loadChildren: '../app/component/component.module#ComponentModule' 
   }
]
```

**component.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserDetailComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'albums',
        loadChildren: '../app/albums/albums.module#AlbumsModule';
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-to-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks Shubham - I had already seen that one and it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I ended up just creating a service from the user detail component which updates the service with the route param i need, and then I access it from there.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary that was query params, he needs route params.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get params url parent id from children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349498/how-to-get-params-url-parent-id-from-children)

Answer (score 4):

`albums` path is child of `UserDetailComponent`'s route, and `UserDetailComponent`'s route is child of `users/:userId`. So when you are inside `albums` route, you should get params of `UserDetailComponent`'s route by routing tree. You can access parent of your route using `ActivatedRoute.parent` (it returns route which is parent of your current route)

Comment: Not really! thats not true, because of the lazy load seems, but I got full path and the paramsMap only return with the one for the child without the parent one